# Is vault's key revocation affect the validity of the revoked key in the services using it?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I was reading the documentation of vault, and came across revocation feature that vault provides. How can revoking a key in vault affect the service descision about the secret, for example a secret for local repository manager that is fetched from vault? 
The only way I am imagining it is that tokens or userpass which are used to authenticate against vault are the ones to e revoked, then it makes sense. But, even if a secret has its lease expired, how would the repository manager know not to accept that secret for authentication?

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance